# Need to install Gnome or KDE on suse: offline installation

Tags: gnome, kde, suse

I need to install a bunch of tools on a suse enterprise distribution for a PoC f a tool. I tried everything on a local VM: I'll have no problems
*EXCEPT*
I connect to the servers (which have a bunch of enterprise restrictions, aka, no internet) using putty.

I would need at some point a Graphical Interface - KDE, Gnome,.. at this point I'm not picky.

I tried searching for a zip of these two that I could unzip and somehow run, however everything I found seems to find is for deb. (and it's not that much either).

Do you have any clue you can give me?
Best,
MCB

Comment: A server don't need a Desktop. Suse don't use *.deb files.  zypper installs *.rpm files.  This is only an information

Comment: I second Bahamut on this. There is no need to run a DE on a server. If you were adamant about this abomination, you would need many packages to get Xorg and a graphical interface running. It is not as simple as downloading a .zip

Comment: I understand that it doesn't use .deb. That was a comment that all I found was useless :)

Comment: My main question is if I can get a GUI for my linux instance. I cannot run zypper install because I have no access to repos...

Comment: I was able to get xming going, but the latency is super slow. I figure i might have to think if there is an alternative solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert the installation disc into your system then Zypper will pick up on it as a local repository that you can use to install the desktop environment.

From the [SUSE documentation](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/book_sle_deployment/data/sec_y2_sw_instsource.html), "By default, the product repositories such as SUSE Linux Enterprise Server-DVD 12 SP2 and a matching update repository are automatically configured after you have registered your system."